# How to see if inner UL is expanded or collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<li class="setRelative">
    <a class="tfLink clickMe current" data-toggle=".tfLink1" id="current" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="theImages/imgPlus.png" id="imgFirstM" class="imgExpCol">Header 1</a>
    <ul class="uSPStyle uSPInner" style="width: 80%;">
        <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Sub-Page" data-toggle=".tf1SLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">Sub-Page</a></li>
        <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="test" data-toggle=".tf2SLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">test</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

By default the `uSPInner` class `Unordered List` is not displayed and is expanded when the `clickMe` link is clicked:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.closest("li").find("ul").slideToggle();

    $('.clickMe').removeClass('current');

    $this.addClass('current');
});
```

How can I add to the above script to see, if the inner `UL` is expanded or collapsed.

Tried this but didn't work:

```
var item = $this.closest("li").find("ul").is(":hidden");
alert(item);
if (item) {
    console.log("no item");
}
else {
    console.log("item");
}
```

Comment: why don't you check if your element has class `current` ?

Comment: Add a variable - in global scope- and save the sate there.

Comment: when you say "didnt work", what DID happen?

Comment: @messerbill because by default the first anchor link always has the current class. Clicking on it, expands the inner UL, if it exists.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge please, provide relevant jsfiddle with proper js, styles and HTML for people to experiment with

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u50b07mz/1/ (as you can see the visible option is always true, even when it is collapsed. I am just trying to change the image when it is expanded and when it is collapsed.

Comment: Another option is to try add a 'hidden' class to ul tag and try toggling class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(this).parent().find("ul").eq(0).is(':visible');` to get the parent of the anchor link you're clicking on, then finding the first child ul and checking if it's displayed on the screen or not. That should give you the correct feedback.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u50b07mz/2/)

Comment: Should just be `$(this).find('img').eq(0).attr('src', 'http://newimg.jpg');` Might be easier having 2 images, one starting with display none and just using `$(this).find('img').toggle();` (I think that'll work)

Comment: Thank you. I just tried `var imgRep = $this.find("img");` and it worked.

Comment: That should return an jquery array of all the images inside of the anchor tag (there's only 1, so no worries there). Glad it worked for you! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/z9wLvgv7/)

```js
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest("li").find("ul").slideToggle();
  $this.toggleClass('current'); //use toggleClass to add and remove the current class

  if ($this.hasClass('current')) { //use hasClass to check for current class
    console.log("no item");
  } else {
    console.log("item");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="setRelative">
  <a class="tfLink clickMe current" data-toggle=".tfLink1" id="current" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img src="theImages/imgPlus.png" id="imgFirstM" class="imgExpCol" />Header 1</a>

  <ul class="uSPStyle uSPInner" style="width: 80%;">
    <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Sub-Page" data-toggle=".tf1SLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">Sub-Page</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="test" data-toggle=".tf2SLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">test</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Docs:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/
http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

---

If for some reason you would prefer to check for visibility:

[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/z9wLvgv7/1/)

```js
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next('ul').is(':hidden')) { // note that order seems to matter here, log before slideToggle
    console.log("no item");
  } else {
    console.log("item");
  }

  $this.closest("li").find("ul").slideToggle();
  $this.toggleClass('current');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="setRelative">
  <a class="tfLink clickMe current" data-toggle=".tfLink1" id="current" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img src="theImages/imgPlus.png" id="imgFirstM" class="imgExpCol" />Header 1</a>

  <ul class="uSPStyle uSPInner" style="width: 80%;">
    <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Sub-Page" data-toggle=".tf1SLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">Sub-Page</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="test" data-toggle=".tf2SLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">test</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

---

You can also use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to check the value of the display property:

[Working Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/z9wLvgv7/2/)

```
  if ($this.next('ul').css('display') == "none") {
    console.log("no item");
  } else {
    console.log("item");
  }
```

```js
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next('ul').css('display') == "none") {
    console.log("no item");
  } else {
    console.log("item");
  }

  $this.closest("li").find("ul").slideToggle();
  $this.toggleClass('current');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="setRelative">
  <a class="tfLink clickMe current" data-toggle=".tfLink1" id="current" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img src="theImages/imgPlus.png" id="imgFirstM" class="imgExpCol" />Header 1</a>

  <ul class="uSPStyle uSPInner" style="width: 80%;">
    <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Sub-Page" data-toggle=".tf1SLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">Sub-Page</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="test" data-toggle=".tf2SLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">test</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: When you click on the main `LI`, if it already has a `current` class, the above code won't work.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I'm not sure what you mean, I didn't change your markup at all. You can add or remove the current class in the markup an both methods still work.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Even using the fiddle you provided, it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/u50b07mz/3/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you expand or collapse a list, a class is added to the element so you can use `.hasClass()` to check if the list is expanded or collapsed.

```
if($(elem).hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')) {
alert('collapsed');
}
```

Comment: I don't think they're using jquery-ui

Comment: In that case, I think checking the display attribute of the <ul> should work. display:none in case of hidden and display:block in case when visible.